# Native solution to use find from vim

Tags: vim, find

I'm on a server, editing some files, and I'm using an account shared with others. I'd like to know if there's a way to use find to get a list of files to edit, just like `:grep` does, but for files. I know *ctrlp.vim*, but I'd rather not install a plugin on a server that is not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *backtick expansion* in an `:edit` command. Example taken from `:help backtick-expansion`:

```
:e `find . -name ver\\*.c -print`
```

If you get 'Too many file names', [just use `:n` or `:args` instead of `:e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034625/why-vim-disallows-globbing-with-e-command)

Also, from the § above in the help, starstar-wildcard is enabled, so you may use

```
:n **/*.c
```

Comment: +1, didn't know the backtick expansion was available here, but I tried and it does not work: I get 'Too many file names'... any idea? EDIT: I found a solution.

Comment: Yeah, `:edit` takes only one argument, but e.g. `:argadd` works for multiple matches.